# How to limit a user to specific OG groups based on user role?

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

In a quite complex project page, I have several user roles (from Drupal core). Further, the page has an internal area which is built upon Organic Groups (OG). There are a lot of groups available, each group is part of a so-called "area". These areas correspond to user roles and what I want to achieve is that users of a role may only subscribe to groups of the area with the same name.

To visualize the concept, let's say I have three user roles (besides anonymous, authenticated and administrator): A, B and C.

There is a node type called "Group" which has a select field for area, the available options are A, B and C.

There are nine groups, called A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2 and C3. I don't want users to apply for a group but immediately join (subscribe) to it, but only if the group's area matches the user's role. So user Alex of role A may only see and join A1 through A3 but not any other group.

The OG group permissions only distinguishes between non-member, member and manager. There's the option to subscribe to a group without approval, which I want. But how to combine that with the Drupal user role?

Answer (score 0):

Due to other restrictions in OG I couldn't overcome, I ended up using the [Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) instead. In addition to other advantages for my use case, it offers some functions to easily add group memberships (these are entities) by using something like

```
$entity_type = 'group_membership';
$entity = entity_create($entity_type, array('gid' => $gid, 'uid' => $uid));
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity_type, $entity);
$wrapper->status = 'active';
$wrapper->added_on = time();
$wrapper->added_by = 1;
$wrapper->save();
```

Adding that into a `hook_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category)` function, I am able to add and revoke memberships based on the updated account's roles.